# Servlets and JSP or Android?

Tags: java

Guys, what do you think, is it more perspective to learn Servlets and JSP or Android? I heard that servlets and JSP are losing its popularity and people more using .NET for websites and developing for Android is more in demand these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java web servers, better solutions than JSP's have been wide spread (JSF with Facelets which is part of Java EE 6), which all boils down to servlets.

What is in greatest demand, depends on where you look.  All technologies are valid seen from their particular perspective, but you will most likely find it nice to specialize.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do something sophisticated with Android, odds are good that you'll need the Servlet knowledge to program a back end server (assuming your Android device is going to connect to a back-end server).